# Redraw image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, uri

Hey guys how do I force an image to redraw ?

More detail --

I have an image on my XAML window which I change the source of programatically, the source changes successfully but the image does not redraw ?

I have tried

```
    image.InvalidateVisual
```

As suggested by some previous posts but that doesn't seem to work in my

Comment: how are *changing the source* as you put it?  more details are goign to be required

Comment: I've got a method that returns an "Image" from a database, I am then setting the imgTile as the returned image. `imgTitle = returnedImg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assign your Imagesource as Null and then assign new ImageSource.

```
MyImage.Source = null;
MyImage.Source = NewSource;
```